# Issues while Displaying/Reading data through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to do is - Before application is ready, it reads some data from one of the external file, make a new dyanamic **"li"**  based on the file content  and then it renders that li on html.

Just to add some explanation - There are two "li" in code
1) Dynamic li - that generates after reading a line from file
2) Static li - that display static li

So, whenever i try to click on "Static link" it calls click event and display me result which works fine.However, when i click on dynamic link, it doesn't trigger the click event

Another thing i noticed, When application is ready it display "its now generating static link first" alert first then it displays "its now generating dynamic link". Potentially, it should display the "dynamically link" alert first and the static link alert afterwards.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="main">

        <header>Open Fulfillment Order</header>

         <div id="ordersList" style="text-align: left">

            <ul id="dynamicList" style="text-align: left;padding-left: 70px;padding-top: 30px">
             </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**File.txt**

```
Order1, 3/15/2017, 2
Order2, 3/10/2017, 3
Order3, 3/30/2017, 4
order4, 3/20/2017, 2
```

**Javascript file**
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
            $.get('file/data.txt', function(data) {
               alert("its now generating dynamic link");

                var lines = data.split("\n");
                for (var prop in lines) {
                 var orderData = lines[prop];

                 var splittedData = orderData.split(","); 
                 // Dynamic link hard coded string will be repalced with actual order name
                 $("#ordersList ul").append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Dynamic Link</span></a></li>');
                }

            });
            alert("its now generating static link first");
            $("#ordersList ul").append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Static Link</span></a></li>');

     });


 $(document).ready(function() { //dom is now loaded in.
     $('#dynamicList li').click(function() {
         alert($(this).find('a').attr('data-value'));    // this will alert data-value value.
                  });
 });
```

Any idea why click event is not being called on Dynamic Link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue could be that when you use

```
$('#dynamicList li').click(function() {
         alert($(this).find('a').attr('data-value'));    // this will alert data-value value.
});
```

jQuery only creates bindings for the `li` elements that currently exist on the page. If `li`s are added later, try using this instead

```
$(document).on('click', '#dynamicList li', function() {
         alert($(this).find('a').attr('data-value'));    // this will alert data-value value.
});
```

Comment: awesome. happy to help